# Difference between fetching data in context and in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I tried to figure out by reading but still don’t get it. I can fetch data rather in context or custom hook and then use it wherever I need but what’s the difference and which one is more suitable. Additionally I would like to know which approach can be used in some kind of react/next chat app where are multiple dbs